# Infinite request to /_ah/queue/__deferred__ AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, queue, infinite-loop, deferred

I'm building an app in Java with google AppEngine. Everything works pretty fine, but in log tab in google app engine console, there's a weird thing happening.

It seems that I have infinite requests to "/_ah/queue/__ deferred__", here is a screenshot :

[Infinite loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUi6Z.jpg)

I went though lot of discussion online but I could not find what it is. I was thinking maybe it was because of filters or listener I had, but after removing them and uploading to the cloud, without even loading a single page, the problem is still here.

I never noticed it before. Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I never found the real problem. But I found out that I was able to manage the queues and tasks in google app engine console [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudtasks). So I deleted all tasks and the loop seems to have stopped. My guess is that each task created another task, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to check that. Hope this won't happen again.